# Conditional '@click' in v-for loop

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

In creating a menu using a list within a v-navigation-drawer, I will loop through a set of items and sub-items with 3 properties amongst others: title (string), location (v-router destination) and clickable (boolean). I'm working off the code [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#expansion-lists) and would like some items to be actual links and others simply open up further menu options and not be clickable.

Code portion is:

```
 <v-list-item
    v-for="subItem in item.items"
    :key="subItem.title"
    @click=""
  >
     <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title"></v-list-item-title>
     </v-list-item-content>
 </v-list-item>
```

My question: how do I get the

```
 @click="subItem.location"
```

only on

```
 v-if:subItem.clickable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add conditions onto the click handler as below.

```
<v-list-item
    v-for="subItem in item.items"
    :key="subItem.title"
    @click="subItem.clickable ? handleByFunction(subItem.location):null"
  >
     <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title"></v-list-item-title>
     </v-list-item-content>
 </v-list-item>
```

```
methods{
  handleByFunction(v){
    console.log(v) 
 }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. You could make that expression a little shorter with `subItem.clickable && handleByFunction(subItem.location)`